# Restore backup table data to old one

Tags: oracle, plsql, backup

I made some changes in my tables and I need to make backup of tables which I use something like

```
CREATE TABLE supplier_invoice_rows_backup
AS
SELECT * FROM supplier_invoice_rows
```

I made changes and I need to return  data from `supplier_invoice_rows_backup` to  `supplier_invoice_rows`
Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is! Try mysql code below.

```
RENAME TABLE supplier_invoice_rows_backup TO supplier_invoice_rows;
```

Or try oracle code.

```
RENAME supplier_invoice_rows_backup TO supplier_invoice_rows;
```

Comment: It will rename table only ? supplier_invoice_rows_backup  to  supplier_invoice_rows ? 
But I want to copy data from supplier_invoice_rows_backup   to supplier_invoice_rows ?

Comment: There is no automated way to copy data from a table to a table. The only way would be to rename the backup table to the new table. The thing you can do is to do it manually and copy each table its data using 'mysqldump' command. Ref: [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/). I don't know if the command works for oracle...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to renaming the table would be to truncate the original table and copy the rows from the 'backup' table:

```
truncate table supplier_invoice_rows;
insert into supplier_invoice_rows (select * from supplier_invoice_rows_backup);
```

Or just reverse your original:

```
drop table supplier_invoice_rows purge;
create table supplier_invoice_rows
as 
select * from supplier_invoice_rows_backup;
```

Or the previously suggested rename.  Your response to that suggestion ("but I want to copy") suggests you haven't thought this through.  You cannot have two tables with the same name in the same schema.  So what do you think is the end result of 'rename table supplier_invoice_rows_backup to supplier_invoice_rows'?